# Backbone: Removing a model without losing the view

Tags: backbone.js, view, model, marionette

I'm trying to remove a model from my collection, but I don't want to lose the view of that model on my front end (it's a summary screen).

I'm using this at the moment to remove the model:

```
groupChats.remove(chatid);
```

Is there any way to do this, or is it not possible? (I'm guessing that somewhere I can unbind the two, but no idea how to, or where it is documented).

Comment: Try suppress collection from triggering `remove` event. From backbone documentation: [link](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove)

Comment: How does the view know that it still cares about a model that is removed? How does it differentiate between a removed model that it should stop displaying and one that should stay up?

Comment: @muistooshort that was the issue I have, I didn't know where to define this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution provided by Cheng Ping Onn in comments:

```
groupChats.remove(chatid, {silent: true});
```